# Question on behavior of a linear function on the boundary

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

"Let $\;U\subset \mathbb R^n\;$ be open and bounded and consider a linear function $\;f:U \to \mathbb R\;$."

Our professor used the above example in the class in order to give us a function which is not necessary zero on $\;\partial U\;$ and now I want to understand why this example was chosen.

As I understand it, for $\;n=1\;$ a non-trivial linear function cannot be zero in both boundary points of the interval $\;U\;$. However for $\;n\gt 1\;$ this argument becomes a little more complicated to me.

I would appreciate if somebody could help me visualize the above in more dimensions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't really know what you are asking. You are speaking of "the above example", but there is no example in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x,y)=x+y$ and let the $U$ be the triangular region in xy plane bounded by $x+y=10$, $x=0,$ and $y=0.$

$f(x,y)$ is a linear function and  $f(x,y)$ on the boundary is not zero except at $(x,y)=(0,0).$